# Julia ArgumentError: Package RCall not found in current path:

Tags: julia, jupyter-lab

I just opened a new Jupyter notebook, and want to load some libraries.

```
using LinearAlgebra
using SparseArrays
using Statistics
using StatsBase
using RCall
```

Everytime I run the cell, I keep on getting the same error:

```
ArgumentError: Package StatsBase not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("StatsBase")` to install the StatsBase package.
```

So I run the suggested commands:

```
import Pkg; Pkg.add("StatsBase")
```

I rerun the top cell, and I get a new error:

```
ArgumentError: Package RCall not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("RCall")` to install the RCall package.
```

What I don't get is why I get these error messages, as have installed these packages previously. If I open one of my pre-existing Jupyter notebooks, whis in a different directory, this error does not occur.  However, if I run Julia in terminal I get the same error. Seemingly it is working in some directories, and not others.
What may be causing the problem?

Comment: have you upgraded Julia recently? for example, `1.5` and `1.6` has different environment, see if those two notebooks have the same Julia kernel

Answer (score 3):

Julia can have many virtual environments. The Julia virtual environment has its own package installation state, independent from the global environment.

Contrary to Python, each environment just keeps links to a package repository in local hard drive rather than contain full copies of each package.

The environment is defined in the `Project.toml` file.

Simply run `Pkg.status()` to check which environment you are working currently with (this time it shows my global environment):

```
julia> Pkg.status()
      Status `C:\JuliaPkg\Julia-1.6.1\environments\v1.6\Project.toml`
  [6e4b80f9] BenchmarkTools v1.1.0
  [1e616198] COSMO v0.8.1
  [336ed68f] CSV v0.8.5
  ...
```

For Jupyter notebooks those are defined in the `Project.toml` that is located at the same folder as your notebook. This is most likely the source of your problems and the reason why you observe "strange" package installation states.

The `Procet.toml` file is normally created when you activate a folder:

```
julia> using Pkg

julia> Pkg.activate(".")
  Activating new environment at `C:\SomeMyFolder\Project.toml`
```

However, when you run Jupyter (e.g. `notebook(dir=".")`) `Pkg.activate(".")` happens automatically where a `Project.toml` file is found in the current folder.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense I think. Do I understand correctly that the virtual environment is defined for each project? I checked, and there definitely is a `Project.toml` in the directory where me pre-existing Jupyter notebooks are located, while there none in the directory where I created the new notebook. The questions then are: how do I define a new virtual environment? ..and how can I decide whether to install packages for a specific virtual environment or for the global environment (accessible to all projects)?

Comment: You do `Pkg.activate("/some/folder")` - see my edits. See also https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/creating-packages/

Comment: So I followed the instructions in the link. 
```julia
(@v1.6) pkg> activate .
  Activating new environment at `~/my/working/directory/Project.toml`

shell> ls
mynotebook1.ipynb mynotebook2..ipynb
```
However, I don't see a `Project.toml`...

Comment: it gets created where you add at least one package dependency: `julia (@v1.6) pkg> add SomePackageName`